# save the changes from JSP table into the database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

I have a table which displays the content of a database. 
I want to save the changes edited in the table to my database.
The problem is no matter what row I edit, each time when I try to save, it takes as parameters the values from the first row.

Main.jsp:

```
<FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST" action="update.jsp">
    <table>
        <% ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {%>
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="id" value="
                <%=rs.getInt("ID") %>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val1" value="<%=rs.getString("Value1") %>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val2" value="<%=rs.getString("Value2") %>"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
</FORM>
```

update.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.io.*,java.util.*,dbcon.SQLConnection" %>
<% String idRez=request.getParameter("id");
    String v1=request.getParameter("val1");
    String v2=request.getParameter("val2");
    SQLConnection.updateDatabase(idRez,Double.parseDouble(v1), Double.parseDouble(v2));
    response.sendRedirect("Main.jsp");
%>
```

Comment: not clear question what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Since all the rows in your `Main.jsp` have the same name(`id`, `val1`, `val2`), whenever you do a `request.getParamater()` call, the 1st matching parameter will be returned.

You can fix this by fetching all the parameter values as follows.

```
String[] ids = request.getParameterValues("id");
```

You will have to modify your `Main.jsp` accordingly to make sure you fetch the correct combination of values in `update.jsp`

However, as you only want to submit the row on which you are clicking `Save`, you can declare `Form` on the row instead of having a Global `Form`.

```
<!--FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST" action="update.jsp"-->
    <table>
        <% ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {%>
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none;">
                <FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST" action="update.jsp">
                <input type="text" name="id" value="
                <%=rs.getInt("ID") %>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val1" value="<%=rs.getString("Value1") %>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val2" value="<%=rs.getString("Value2") %>"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save"></FORM></td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
<!--/FORM-->
```

Comment: I want to save to database only the parameters on the line that I press that button. How can I know which row corresponds to the button I clicked?

Comment: @BONIETTE Updated the answer.